# Failing to deploy watchface on Gear S2

Tags: tizen

I have an app that I'm trying to deploy to my own Gear S2. I have generated all the required certificates with Samsung by following:

http://developer.samsung.com/gear/develop/getting-certificates/create-certificates

When I try to Run as Tizen Web Application from the IDE everything seems to work fine, I get no error, but nothing gets deployed on the watch. I still see the old watchface.

Comment: Although the answer of @srkushhwakha is correct, the problem was another one. A collaborator has commented out the `<tizen:category name="com.samsung.wmanager.WATCH_CLOCK"/>` line from the `config.xml`. After adding it back again, now the watchface is deployed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to long tap on the watch screen where the watchface is shown, then browse watchfaces on your watch by left or right swipe/beezel rotate. And click on your watchface to set it.